# Replace some component value in a vector with some other value

Tags: r

In R, in a vector, i.e. a 1-dim matrix, I would like to change components with value 3 to with value 1, and components with value 4 with value 2. How shall I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Actually in R vectors are not 1-dim matrices (and are not matrices at all). They do have length but not dimensions, at least not ones that the `dim` function will return. This is not a trivial nitpicking exercise. Many errors result from not understanding the details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The idiomatic r way is to use `[<-`, in the form 
`x[index] <- result`

If you are dealing with integers / factors or character variables, then `==` will work reliably for the indexing,

```
x <- rep(1:5,3)
x[x==3] <- 1
x[x==4] <- 2

x
## [1] 1 2 1 2 5 1 2 1 2 5 1 2 1 2 5
```

---

The `car` has a useful function `recode` (which is a wrapper for `[<-`), that will let you combine all the recoding in a single call

eg

```
library(car)

x <- rep(1:5,3)

xr <- recode(x, '3=1; 4=2')

x
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
xr
## [1] 1 2 1 2 5 1 2 1 2 5 1 2 1 2 5
```

---

Thanks to @joran for mentioning `mapvalues` from the `plyr` package, another wrapper for `[<-`

```
x <- rep(1:5,3)
mapvalues(x, from = c(3,1), to = c(1,2))
```

`plyr::revalue` is a wrapper for `mapvalues` specifically  `factor` or `character` variables.

Comment: +1 for `recode()`, I've never seen it before, but will definitely keep it in my toolbox from here on.

Comment: There is also `revalue` and `mapvalues` in the **plyr** package.